# save method does not validate duplicate email if save button is clicked multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`record.save` method does not validate unique email in rails .

following validation has been added .

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => { :message => 'Sorry, this Email address has already been used for an account.' }
```

if javascript is disabled from the browser and we double clicked on the submit button to register . It creates users with same email without validating.

what could be the reason?

Comment: one way is that you can disable the button on click and then re-enable that button after successfully return from server.

Comment: Did my answer help you understanding your issue?

Comment: Yes @Marek, I have a large number of records in users table. What will be the best solutions to a fix. Can I add an index for unique ness in email. I still don't know how many records present with duplicate emails.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you try to validate second record while the first one isn't saved yet. To assure uniqueness, you should create unique index on e-mail.

For reference: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations